# rsync -H with --link-dest and potential link corruption

Tags: rsync, corruption, hardlink

`man rsync` for `-H` includes:

*"If you specify a --link-dest directory that contains hard links, the linking of the destination files against the --link-dest files can cause some paths in the destination to become linked together due to the --link-dest associations."*

Can anyone explain how and why this happens and/or what type of scenario might lead to it?

Thanks